# How to use RGB text colours in lazarus console

Tags: console, pascal, lazarus

I'm using lazarus console, and im aware you have a set of basic colours that can be accessed through use of textcolor() but I want to know if there is a way to instead use RGB colours? I haven't been able to find a method for console online.
Thanks.

Comment: No. Each character in the console consists of a char and a color and such a color has 8 buts, 4 for the background and 4 for the foreground (text) color. There is no way to use any other colors than the basic ones in a console.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, that's a bit disappointing, guess ill have to make do or maybe move my code over to a different language, i'm not too far into coding it so it should be fine.

Comment: Why do you think the colours available to a console app depend on the language you are using?

Comment: I would likely be looking at moving it off of console, but if I do so using a different language would be easier, for me anyways.

Comment: @Geeekoid: FreePascal and Delphi are RAD. **There are no better languages than these two to move away from the console** as well as to program for the console. They make using and designing a GUI really easy. In [Delphi](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter), you can use the VCL, for Windows, or FMX for cross-platform. In [FreePascal/Lazarus](https://www.lazarus-ide.org/), you can use the LCL for both.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, Fwiw, I completely agree witth you and hope that the OP takes note.

Comment: Hmm, I used some object pascal (that is whats it's called right?) and it seems simple enough, Thank you for the information, Considering I know more pascal than any other so ill begin looking to trying my code in object pascal. Many thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$RGBA = textcolor("#RRGGBBAA"); 

$RGB = textcolor("#RRGGBB");
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work?

Comment: The console is just another window, which supports the full range. The conventional publications are outdated this point. As time of TurboPascal we used the mode-change to adress the true colors. Today is the stage anotherone. Fastest way to realize has shown. You also can use the extralong to improve the requirements of ressources. I'am a coder and i love fastest hardstyle. There are others, that lames the scene with false expections.

Comment: Admittedly I don't need this answer anymore, but I'm still grateful someone would finally give me an answer. Thanks!